# IE 11 "An error has occurred in the script on this page" at the end of the line

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, error-handling, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to test a legacy web site originally intended to work on IE8 in IE11.

I get an error as "An Error has occurred in the script on this page." on my code when accessing the page on IE11 (it works fine on IE8). The line number stated here is the last line of clientCXMLDocument.js file and I don't see any issue in that code that would case the issue.

[image: Error]

On IE11 in Internet Options, if I uncheck "Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)", I no longer get the error but I would be more interested to know what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of API featured removed and replaced in IE11 as listed in this documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx

For example, the use of document.selection will no longer work in IE11 so your javascipt code may contain some of these and use the corresponding replacements.

In the meantime while you are fixing the code, you might want to use the IE X-UA tag to specify the IE8 legacy document mode

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```